# caret train not outputting progress

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to see the progress of training in `caret`. I have set up the following

```
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = t.folds,
  repeats = t.repeats,
  seeds = seeds,
  returnData = FALSE,
  verboseIter = TRUE
  )

caret.trainmodel <- function(method, workers=2, ...) {
  # prepare parallel processing
  cl <- makeCluster(workers)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  # start training
  set.seed(825)
  cat(paste("\n",method, "Training start \n"))
  pt <- proc.time()
  trained.model <- train(count.bins ~ ., data = training,
                   method = method,
                   trControl = fitControl,
                   verbose = TRUE,
                   ...
                   )
  cat(paste("Done", proc.time()-pt, "\n"))

  # release worker
  stopCluster(cl)

  return(trained.model)  
}
```

I call the above e.g. `caret.trainmodel("rpart")` and was expecting to see progress e.g. which fold / repetition it is on now. But despite `verboseIter=TRUE` in the control and `verbose=TRUE` in the `train` call, nothing is displaying on the screen. Is there anything else I need to set?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `verbose = TRUE` in the `train` function doesn't do anything as this is not an explicit argument to `train`, nor to the `rpart` function. 
Do you get the expected printed material when not running in parallel?

Comment: Yes it prints when not in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my comment above, try specifying the argument `outfile` in the `makeCluster` function.

```
    makeCluster(workers,outfile = "")
```

See `?makeCluster` for further details

Comment: I just tried it without parallel as you suggested in the comment section, and it does output the progress. However specifying the argument above for the `makeCluster` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What operating system are you working on? The above solves it for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Something else that might be useful to know, what is the result of `parallel:::getClusterOption("type")`

Comment: The above returns `"PSOCK"`. I'm running on Windows 7.